# JQuery click event triggered on Chrome and FF device touch emulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, click, touch

In my Rails site, I have an element that I want to act as a link when clicked by a mouse (e.g. on a desktop), but not when touched on a touch-screen device (because there is also a hover behavior).

My understanding is that the JQuery .click event should not get triggered on a touch.

My coffeescript for setting the click handler is simply

```
...
    $(this).click ->
      location.href = url
...
```

(where "this" is the element in question)

I know this code works, because the click action works with the mouse. To ensure that it doesn't get triggered on a touch device, I use the device emulation in Chrome's Developer Tools to emulate a touch. However, when I do this, the method still fires and follows the link.

Is this a problem with the Chrome emulation or with my code? I want to know whether it will behave this way on real touch devices.

edit: Same thing happens with Firefox, so I'm thinking it's my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that touch events trigger click events as well, later on in the event chain. To get the functionality I wanted,  I kept the `.click` handler, but added a `.touchstart` handler where I called `event.preventDefault()` to short-circuit the rest of the event chain. This way, the `.click` handler fires for mouse clicks, but not for touches.